# angularfire equivalent to .name()

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am able to load my data object using the $firebase function, but how do I get the data object's name?  With the core Firebase API, I can call the [.name()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/name.html) method to get it.

And angularfire provides the [$getIndex()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#getindex) to get the names of the child data, but I can't figure out how to get the name of the root element.

Inside one function, I am loading the root element with a URL: FBURL+'/profiles/'+profileID
So profileID is what I am trying to retrieve, but in a different function from the loader.

I am trying to keep the code and data tree clean, so I'd like to avoid passing profileID around as its own argument, and I'd like to avoid storing the element's name as a child property in the data tree.

Comment: There's an open ticket to add the `$id` property that will give you the name: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/187

Comment: awesome, you made the patch!  Thanks Anant!